# Как отфильтровать по колонке в таком порядке? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть таблица projects
и там есть поля updated_at и states (enum:"Обработка","Активный","Открытый","Закрытый")

Мне нужно отфильтровать поля сначала по updated_at (по убыванию --> это я сделал orderBy('updated_at','desc')), однако с enum-списком все тяжелее.

Мне нужно, чтобы проекты выводились таким образом --> Сначала открытые,затем активные и только потом закрытые.

Думал я по поводу сортировки в обратном алфавитном порядке, однако здесь это неприменимо, так как "закрытый" находится прям посередине, а нужно, чтобы в конце.

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип enum по сути - число, значения "Обработка", "Активный", "Открытый", "Закрытый" хранятся как мета-информация таблицы.

Это число соответствует порядку объявления в DDL таблицы, для текущей последовательности "Обработка" == 1, "Закрытый" == 4.

Для сортировки используется SQL-выражение `CASE ...`. И тут я нашел ваш вопрос и [ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64569878/9435985):

```
$query->orderByRaw("CASE state
    WHEN 'open' THEN 1
    WHEN 'active' THEN 2
    WHEN 'closed' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END");
```

Такое решение работает, но сразу скажу, что на больших объемах данных (сотни тысяч строк и выше) и при большой выборке данных (сортировка всех заказов по статусу с пагинацией) оно будет тормозить. Почему?

Дело в том, что движку РСУБД для определения порядка нужно будет пройти по всем записям и сделать `CASE state`, то есть вычислить поле. Если же `enum` заменить на `integer` как
внешний ключ на другую таблицу, в которой прописать порядок сортировки по-умолчанию `sort`, РСУБД может использовать индексы. Поэтому будет быстрее.

И еще добавлю [почему enum-зло](http://pushorigin.ru/sql/enum-evel)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Еще хотелось бы спросить ,почему orderByRaw работает только перед orderBy?
orderBy()->orderByRaw() так не работает, вот тестил только сегодня...

Comment: Работает в обоих случаях. Просто когда добавляется несколько orderBy, сначала сортируется по первой колонке (или вычисляемому полю), и если записи имеют одинаковое значение первой колонки, то в пределах этих строк еще сортируется по второму полю.